# Babylon.js and webpack error : [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS

Tags: typescript, webpack, babylonjs

When I run I'm getting full of error in the console when the scene is loading:

```
 npm run start
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Debugger attached.

> proj1@1.0.0 start
> webpack-dev-server --port 8080

Debugger attached.
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://10.100.102.13:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'C:\dev\my\js\babylon\proj1\public' directory
asset js/bundleName.js 24.4 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 206 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 27.3 KiB 12 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/@babylonjs/core/ 10 MiB 1168 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/@babylonjs/gui/ 1.08 MiB 113 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/@babylonjs/materials/ 321 KiB 60 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/@babylonjs/loaders/ 441 KiB 53 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/@babylonjs/serializers/ 252 KiB 29 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 71.8 KiB 16 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 5.3 KiB
  ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 1.94 KiB [built] [code generated]
  + 3 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 81.6 KiB
  ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/index.js 7.74 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/named-references.js 73 KiB [built] [code generated]
  + 2 modules
+ 5 modules
webpack 5.87.0 compiled successfully in 12117 ms
```

app.js:

```
import "@babylonjs/core/Debug/debugLayer";
import "@babylonjs/inspector";
import "@babylonjs/loaders/glTF";
import { Engine, Scene, ArcRotateCamera, Vector3, HemisphericLight, Mesh, MeshBuilder } from "@babylonjs/core";

class App {
    constructor() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.style.width = "100%";
        canvas.style.height = "100%";
        canvas.id = "gameCanvas";
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        var engine = new Engine(canvas,true);
        var scene = new Scene(engine);

        var camera: ArcRotateCamera = new ArcRotateCamera("Camera",Math.PI/2,Math.PI/2,2,Vector3.Zero(),scene);
        camera.attachControl(canvas,true);
        var light1:HemisphericLight = new HemisphericLight("light1",new Vector3(1,1,0),scene);
        var sphare:Mesh = MeshBuilder.CreateSphere("sphere",{ diameter:1},scene);

        window.addEventListener("keydown",(ev) =>{
            if(ev.shiftKey && ev.ctrlKey && ev.altKey && ev.key == 'i') {
                if(scene.debugLayer.isVisible()){
                    scene.debugLayer.hide();
                } else {
                    scene.debugLayer.show();
                }
            } 
        });


        engine.runRenderLoop(()=>{
            scene.render();
        });


    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "proj1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 8080"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babylonjs/core": "^6.8.0",
    "@babylonjs/inspector": "^6.8.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.87.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noResolve": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "preserveConstEnums":true,
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es6"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(appDirectory, "src/app.ts"), //path to the main .ts file
    output: {
        filename: "js/bundleName.js", //name for the js file that is created/compiled in memory
        clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    devServer: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        port: 8080, //port that we're using for local host (localhost:8080)
        static: path.resolve(appDirectory, "public"), //tells webpack to serve from the public folder
        hot: true,
        devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: "/",
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: path.resolve(appDirectory, "public/index.html"),
        })
    ],
    mode: "development",
};
```

```
[webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement enabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled.
log.js:39 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
babylon.guiEditor.max.js:33066 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
babylon.inspector.bundle.max.js:34125 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
:8080/favicon.ico:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack://proj1/node_modules/@babylonjs/core/Debug/debugLayer.js.map: Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for webpack://proj1/node_modules/@babylonjs/core/Misc/tools.js.map: Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Comment: Please always run an English spell-checker on your questions prior to posting. As a prolific poster new readers will look to you to set an example for the kind of quality we are seeking (community disagreement/strike with Stack Overflow Inc notwithstanding).